# USB Graphics Card for Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know about a USB Graphics card that has drivers that function in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? The graphics card on my PC does not support multi-display functionality in Ubuntu OR RViz feeds from the kinect sensor...

Any suggestions on a good USB graphics card with Linux drivers?

Thanks!
Andy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53529/usb-graphics-card-for-ubuntu-12.04lts/) by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-01-29**:
What devices is your PC made of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Andy, a USB graphics adapter is a waste of money. Why don't you tell everyone what your ROS project is, then they can help you better? You don't mention if it must be a laptop, or battery operated?

The easiest path is to get yourself a spare desktop PC (can be second hand) with a nice NVidia graphics card. Setup a fresh Ubuntu install and you'll be set.

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1